# Microsoft Project pool resources - count problem

Tags: vba, count, resources, ms-project

code from learn.microsoft:

```
Dim R As Long, Names As String 
For R = 1 To ActiveProject.Resources.Count 
 Names = ActiveProject.Resources(R).Name & ", " & Names 
Next R 
MsgBox Names
```

Works great when resources are defined in project file.
But when you use resources only in subprojects `Resources collection` is empty.

Adding new resource manually does not any changes - still count 0.
Using ribbon and Add Resources - counts this resource but other not.

How can I count resources from subprojects in main project?

When I terminate link to subprojects `Resources collection` count correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sebastian, I ran your code on a resource pool file and it works fine, as long as the sharing link can point to the pool file, or if the resource pool file is open. However, the code presents resource names but your question relates to a simple count of resources. The latter can be obtained with the simple statement in the VBE Immediate window: Print ActiveProject.Resources.Count

Comment: Please run this code in project with subproject which use resource pool (project's resources only from subproject's resource pool).
I get number of resources from ActiveProject.Resources.Count in debug mode and this is not a problem.
Problem is when you running this code in project with subprojects which use resources only from pool. When main project haven't any own resources.
This error exist also when main project haven't any own resources but subprojects have own resources even without pool resource.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian, There is no error. I assume the "main project" you reference is a dynamic master. In a master project, subprojects are not part of the master, rather, the master contains pointers to each subproject. So when you run code in a master that loops through the Active.Project, the loop is looking for objects in the master and the master has no resource objects. Here is a modified version of your macro that will show the names of all resources in the resource pool, assuming all subprojects are using the pool. If there is a mixture of subprojects sharing and/or using their own resources the code will need to be modified.

```
Names As String
Dim Res As Resource
For Each Res In ActiveProject.Subprojects(1).SourceProject.Resources
    Names = Res.Name & ", " & Names
Next Res
MsgBox Names
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by john-project solves the problem.

Browsing a resource collection with `Resources collection` remains problematic in one more situation: the project file contains its own resources separated by a blank line inserted with the insert key.
Such a line has an identifier but all fields are empty. Browsing resources using a collection generates an error (e.g. when reading the resource name).